# Search bar implementation not working. Code does not search anything

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a search bar. Data is presented in a ListView and fetched from a JSON File. Please help me to query the data in the search bar properly.

For simplification I removed some features, but basically inside my Widget build(BuildContext) I got:

```
 return MaterialApp(
  home:Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
              title: _searchBar(notesForDisplay, newData),
              
              body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/gradient_blue.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: FutureBuilder(
              future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('files/myfile.json'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // Decode the JSON
                  var newData =json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                  notesForDisplay.addAll(newData);

                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        String word = newData[index]['VERB'];
                        String meaning = newData[index]['MEANING'];
                        bool isSaved = savedWords.contains(word);

                        return  _listItem(index,notesForDisplay, isSaved, word, meaning);
                      },
                      itemCount: notesForDisplay.length);
                },
              ),
            )));
  }



 _searchBar(notesForDisplay, newData) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search..'),
        onChanged: (text) {
          text = text.toLowerCase();
          setState(() {
            notesForDisplay = newData.where((note) {
              var noteTitle = note[index]['VERB'].toLowerCase();
              return noteTitle.contains(text);
            }).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

My _listItem widget is like:

```
_listItem(index,notesForDisplay, isSaved, word, meaning) {
    return Card(
            children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                         InkWell(
                           child: RichText(
                           text: TextSpan(
                           children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: notesForDisplay[index]['VERB'],
```

Comment: How do you call `_searchBar`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: The widget raises an exception: 'where'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Null'] and I noticed where is in "grey" color?¿?

Comment: It should be this one `var newData =json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());`. Remove the `var`. I also find something strange in your coding, maybe even you fix this part, your list may not update. It is because when you `setState`, you retrieve list from json file every time. May I suggest you load the json file in `initState`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> notesForWhole = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> notesForDisplay = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    /// load file in initState
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      String jsonFile =
          await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('files/myfile.json');
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonFile);
      /// original data store in [notesForWhole]
      /// filtered data store in [notesForDisplay]
      notesForWhole.addAll(jsonData);
      notesForDisplay.addAll(jsonData);
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
              title: _searchBar(notesForWhole),
            ),
            body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('images/gradient_blue.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                /// ListView depends on [notesForDisplay]
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      String word = notesForDisplay[index]['VERB'];
                      String meaning = notesForDisplay[index]['MEANING'];
                      bool isSaved = savedWords.contains(word);

                      return _listItem(
                          index, notesForDisplay, isSaved, word, meaning);
                    },
                    itemCount: notesForDisplay.length))));
  }

  Widget _searchBar(List<Map<String, dynamic>> notesForWhole) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search..'),
        onChanged: (text) {
          /// [_searchBar] only update the [notesForDisplay]
          /// filter data
          text = text.toLowerCase();
          setState(() {
            notesForDisplay = notesForWhole.where((note) {
              var noteTitle = note['VERB'].toLowerCase();
              return noteTitle.contains(text);
            }).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is totally broken, and I do not know where could be the mistake. How would you integrate your code with this kind of Json data {"VERB": "ASK  OUT", "MEANING": "To invite on a date"}? Totally lost with this

Comment: What do you mean `broken`? Any error showed? Cannot compile? No Result? Please more specific.

Comment: It says "Incorrect use of ParentWidget" and List do not show up. Could you put an example with a valid use of Widget with ListView?

Comment: `Incorrect use of ParentWidget` could be your code error in `_listItem`, you may use `Expanded`,`Positioned` or `Spacer` in `ListView`. Even  `_listItem` you post in question has syntax error. There is a way you still can try, add `shrinkWrap : true` to `ListView`